# Converting nodes and links to hierarchical tree in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tree, force-layout

I have a JSON representing a graph (also in my case a tree) whi lookx like this:

```
{"directed": true, "graph": [], 
"nodes": [{"time": 4, "id": 4551308, "name": "Alto da Boa Vista"}, {"time": 7, "id": 4551309, "name": "Sumare"},
...
"links": [{"source": 0, "target": 36, "weight": 1}, 
{"source": 1, "target": 36, "weight": 1},
...
```

In order to use it to build a tree like in this example, http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html, I need to convert this JSON in a hierarchical object with children nodes nested within the parents as illustrated here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#wiki-tree.

Does D3 have some built-in function to convert from graph to tree?
or how would you go about generating a nested tree JSON objetc from  graph?

I have the example in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fccoelho/bFT8K/8/

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I'm looking to get my already prepared `nodes` and `links` json array converted into hierarchical formatted json, without me needing to re-write full json generation code.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this is a 2 part answer.

**Part 1:**
D3 does have built in functionality to turn arrays into nested structures.  Have a look at the d3.nest() function

- API Documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#nests

This is mostly meant for hierarchical layouts: Cluster, Pack, Partition, Treemap

**Part 2:**
If you are trying to achieve a layout similar to the example you posted then you don't need to do anything to your data.  That example uses a force layout which expects a graph. Since the force layout can handle a graph of any shape and a tree is just a graph that adheres to a few constraints you don't need to do any conversion.  If the shape of your graph happens to be a tree it will look like a tree.

This should be good enough:

```
force
  .nodes(spread.nodes)
  .links(spread.links)
  .start();
```

Comment: using force i can get x,y positions but it's not looks like tree it like all nodes comes in random I need to be set them like tree or in some arrangement

Comment: kindly update the documentation link to https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#nests